# How to set up a Generic workflow logic in Microsoft purview?

Tags: workflow, azure-purview

In setting up the workflow for cud action for a business glossary terms in purview
I target to apply some logic like term.parent.parent.steward

I wonder if that is possible and if there is any documentation i can review

Is there a way to apply a generic approach in setting up the workflow?

At the moment i am using the web UI for the setting, in the UI it seems like only a limited amount of pre-settled object are available
For example , i can see the name attribute term to be created as term[‘name’] in the pre-setted terms but not possible to go further like term.parent.parent.name for exmaple

Comment: I have tried researching around this issue and have not found a way to achieve this, Purview does not seem to support custom workflow logic currently.